# how to align buttons from left to right

Tags: c#, winforms

So I was digging around to get some ideas on how to create buttons dynamically. I found a [post](http://bitvector.net/?p=41) which I was able to incorporate into my project. Unfortunately, these buttons are created vertically. Is there a way in windows form to align them horizontally from left to right?

Comment: Have you tired creating the buttons inside a FlowLayoutPanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the location property for each button:

```
int lastX = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  Button b = new Button();
  b.Location = new Point(lastX, 0);
  this.Controls.Add(b);
  lastX += b.Width;
}
```

Comment: Wow, a down vote for placing buttons left to right as the OP wanted.  Tough crowd.

Comment: This seems to have worked for me. Thank you very much. To everyone who gave their opinion and suggestions, I will keep them in mind if further down the road, this solution doesnt work correctly. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a good case for the [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) control. We had some old code that was moving buttons around relative to each other. I replaced it with a FlowLayoutPanel and it made life much easier.

You can have the buttons laid out horizontally or vertically, set padding around each button to space them equally apart, set properties for aligning the controls within the panel, allow them to flow into multiple rows if the user resizes the form, etc. Makes maintenance later on a lot easier too. Imagine adding a button to the middle of 10 others and then having to make manual adjustments so the buttons don't overlap one another, etc.

It sounds like you wouldn't have that last issue though, since you're creating them dynamically at runtime. Still, you could create a button and place it into the FlowLayoutPanel, and let the control handle the actual placement of it relative to other controls. Plus you wouldn't have to worry about moving them around if the user resized the form, as long as you're okay with multiple rows of buttons...